# return binary number from Python dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, binary

I have the dictionary like this:

```py
{0: True, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False, 6: '3.5'}
```

I need to make binary number from first 5 values `(True=1, False=0)` and get `10000`

Help :)

Comment: Whats stopping you? What have you done so far?

Comment: Nothing. I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a functional solution:

```
''.join(map(str, map(int, map(d.get, range(5)))))
```

Comment: Thank you John.
Can you explain this to me? What is the map here... I couldn't find it in Python reference? 
d is dictionary I suppose.
As far as I found, Join returns keys not values!